# MongoDB connection error while deploying on ZEIT

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor, graphql, vercel

i am new at React and i'm trying to deploy on zeit. Deploy is successful but on zeit it gives error like

> /usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
>                           throw(ex);
>                           ^

```
Error: query parameter ssl is an incomplete value pair
    at module.exports (/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:47:15)
    at connect (/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:401:16)
    at Function.MongoClient.connect (/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:225:3)
    at new MongoConnection (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:169:11)
    at new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:4:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (packages/mongo/remote_collection_driver.js:38:10)
    at Object.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver (packages/underscore.js:784:19)
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:99:40)
    at AccountsServer.AccountsCommon (packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js:23:18)
    at new AccountsServer (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:18:5)
```

if anyone also get same error then please help.

Answer (score 1):

I face the same error, For me this was happening because i didn't pass the ssl parameter with value true.

```
ssl=true
```

with my mongo url, so the complete url now looks like

```
mongourl://yoururl?ssl=true&otherparameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is from `mongodb/lib/url_parser.js` which means there's probably a problem with your `MONGO_URL`, perhaps around the SSL part.

https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#MONGO-URL

Comment: i checked everything and tried my best but nothing found helpful